# Why can't I set id in javascript the way I can set className?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I googled but couldn't get a satisfactory answer.
I am new to JS.

What I am doing is, creating a button with a number written on it and whenever the user clicks on the button, the number increments by one.

```js
var newButton = document.createElement('Button');
newButton.id = "btn";
newButton.innerHTML = "0";
newButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  newButton.innerHTML = String(Number(newButton.innerHTML) + 1);
});
document.body.appendChild(newButton);
```

```css
#btn {
  width: 96px;
  height: 48px;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!--Where the CSS is loaded in-->
  <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/button.css" type="text/css">-->
</head>

<body>
  <!--Where the JS is loaded in-->
  <!--<script src="js/button.js" type="text/javascript"></script>-->
</body>

</html>
```

Now, this does display a button and increment the number on it, but the css doesn't reflect in the displayed button.
Instead if my button.js is like this

```
    var newButton = document.createElement('Button');
    newButton.id = "btn";
    newButton.className = "BtnClass";
    newButton.innerHTML = "0";
    newButton.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
       newButton.innerHTML = String(Number(newButton.innerHTML) + 1);
   });
    document.body.appendChild(newButton);
```

And button.css styles it by class rather than id,

```
.BtnClass{  width: 96px;
    height: 48px;
    font-size: 24px;}
```

Then it properly displays the button in the way I want it to.

Why doesn't this happen when I style with the id name but works fine when I style by the class name?

Update - Works fine, it was probably some setting specific to the coding site I was using.

Comment: The CSS in your first example seems to work fine.

Comment: Looks ok to me: https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-stonebraker-4zbz7?file=/src/index.js

Comment: @Ivar Okay, now that I run here, it works fine indeed. Wasn't working fine in HackerEarth. Must be some specific setting in HackerEarth, right?

Comment: @godwa_rao I don't know HackerEarth, so can't tell. All I can tell that it _should_ for the example you provided.

Comment: @Ivar okay, thanks.